Is it permissible to develop a game that relies on luck?
So I have been doing programming for over a year now and have tried my best to enjoy it while being distant from haram programming stuff such as building projects that might encourage haram in some sense.
Recently I started building a ludo game which involved dice. Since usage of dice is not permissible in islam I removed dice from the game and replaced it with a simple button that generates a random number(ie : luck).
I know that playing games that rely on luck isnt allowed , but I am not playing it(nor encouraging others to play) instead creating it. I have interest in problem solving and state management which basically makes an programmer think for all the finite cases that one move(luck) can cause.
I firmly believe this strengthen my problem solving skills. Let me know if this counts as haram in some sense , if yes then i'll happily leave it for the sake of Allah. Jazakallah
